# Multiple if statement in loop condition

Tags: r, estimation

I am a Phd student in the university of Padua and I am trying to write a little script (the first!) in R cran v. 3.0.1 to make a simulation on epidemiology. 
I'd like to change the values of a vector of 883 values basing on a neighbour matrix constructed with nb2mat from a shapefile: if i and j (two cells) are neighbour (matrix) and i or j have a positive value in the vector, I'd like to transform the value of both i and j to 1 (positive), otherwise the value of i and j should remain 0. When I launch the next little script:

```
for(i in 1:883) 
 { for(j in 1:883) 
  { if(MatriceDist[i,j] > 0 & ((vectorID[i] > 0 | vectorID[j] > 0)) { 
         vectorID[i] = 1 & vectorID[j] = 1 
                print(vectorID) 
 } } }
```

the answer from the software is:

```
Error: unexpected '{' in: 
" { for(j in 1:883) 
 { while(MatriceDist[i,j] > 0 & ((vectorID[i] > 0 | vectorID[j] > 0)) {"
```

I think that it is an error in the statement for if but I can not understand how to solve it... 
Thank you everyone! 
Elisa

Comment: I agree this question is off-topic here, as it has no statistical content. Personally I think it is of too low quality for stackoverflow too. @Phalaen: The error you list does not match the code (while vs. if). There is a ) parentheses missing in the if clause after >0)) - or one too much in ((vectorID[i] - and the clause body doesn't make much sense too me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming. 

Answer (score 1):

check your brackets :-)

```
for(i in 1:883) { 
    for(j in 1:883) { 
        if(MatriceDist[i,j] > 0 & (vectorID[i] > 0 | vectorID[j] > 0)) { vectorID[i] = 1 & vectorID[j] = 1 print(vectorID) 
        } 
    } 
}
```

you had one `(` to mucch before `vectorID` in your `if` statement.

please double check is the condition now specified in the statement is still the one you require.

btw: for loops are very slow in R. If you know the end size of `vectorID`, try pre-allocating the full matrix. That will speed things up a little bit.